# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I am trying to create a trigger that decreminate the number of books based on the value inserted in the other table. I am using the following code

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateStock 
ON dbo.command
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.book
    SET number = number - (SELECT quant FROM inserted)
    WHERE NLIV = SELECT NLIV FROM inserted
```

But I am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. Incorrect syntax near ')'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the right syntax for an `UPDATE` if you need to `join` with another table. Try the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateStock 
ON dbo.command
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE b
SET b.number = b.number - i.quant
FROM dbo.book b
INNER JOIN INSERTED i
    ON b.NLIV = i.NLIV;

END
```

Comment: i am getting the error: incorrect syntax near the ';'

Comment: @Hen updated my answer. Add the `END` after the `UPDATE`